# Audio drifts when concatenating clips

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I am trying to concatenate a bunch of short, 1-second video clips in ts format using the following command:

```
var convertCommand = "cd clips; ffmpeg -y -i concat:\"" + convertedFilenames.join("|") + "\" -c:a aac -strict experimental -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc \"" + user._id + ".mp4\"; mv \"" + user._id + ".mp4\" \"full/" + user._id + ".mp4\"";
```

This works great, however, the audio "drifts" very slowly, and after about 15 seconds, the audio has been delayed by about 1 second.

Is there a way I can encode audio differently to avoid this? Does this have to do with these commands?

```
-c:a aac -strict experimental -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc
```

For completion, this is the script used to trim the clips first into 1 second clips:

```
cd clips; ffmpeg -y -i ./converted/${1}.ts -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:01 -vcodec libx264 -acodec libvo_aacenc -y  ./converted/${1}_trimmed.ts;
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is audio recorded at 48 kHz but played back at 44.1 kHz.  The concatenation isn't going to convert that audio for you... it's simply muxing into the right container.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! I am very new to audio / video processing - can you explain in a bit more detail how I could make sure that recorded and played back audio will be in sync at the same kHz? Would that be something I do when I convert the clips? Thanks